# Work that was not done on time

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for a word for something that was not done on time, but has to be eventually.

> If you don't complete this assignment this week, it will be your _____(debt?) for the next one.

The answer should be something else, but backlog item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to say that the unfinished task will become an addition to the subsequent task that will be assigned, you can use ***carry over***.

> : to persist from one stage or sphere of activity to another
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carryover)</sub>

In your sample:

> *If you don't complete this assignment this week, it will **carry over** to your next one.*

If you want to say that the unfinished task will make the next task particularly burdensome, you can use ***pile on***.

> to increase something by a large amount, or to do it a lot
>   <sub>[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/pile-on)</sub>

In your sample:

> *If you don't complete this assignment this week, it will **pile on** to your next one.*

Answer (score 1):

**Albatross**

*If you don't complete this assignment this week, it will be your albatross for the next one.*

(a metaphor of encumbrance or burden)

'Fame has become the **albatross** that prevents her from leading a normal life.'

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/albatross

Answer (score 0):

*If you don't complete this assignment this week, it will be added to your backlog for next week.*

Though that's kind of confusingly redundant.  Normally one would say simply "added to your backlog" or something like "it will become one of your assignments for next week."

Answer (score 0):

It's **you're** baby!

It may be too non-PC to dare saying these days, but it sure has the meaning of there is no way you can drop this or pass it on to anyone else.